# Horizontal and Vertical recyclerview item position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview like google play store. am able to render items properly but when i add onclicklistener inside horizontal recyclerview am getting only horizontal item position, How to get veritcal recyclerview item position to get the clicked item completely from model class.?

Comment: Here a link to a tutorial http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html

Comment: i have updated the answer..if you have any problem please update..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a `List<Vertical>` *for outer recyclerView* and a field of vertical list is `List<Horizontal>` *for inner horizontal recyclerview* Vertical object should be like this..

```
public class Vertical {

  //int vertical_Postion;
  List<Horizontal> horizontalList;


}
```

**In recyclerAdapter Vertical (onBindViewHolder()) pass the position to the constructor** like this..

```
   int vertical_position = position; // position you get in the onBindViewHolder
   RecylerAdapterHorizontal horizontal = new RecyclerAdapterHorizontal(context,horizontalList,vertical_postion);
   rv_horizontal.setAdapter(horizontal);
```

**Now you can log the vertical postion in the reycler Adapter horizontal.. it will be constant for one horizontal list**

**Edit**

```
HorizontalAdapter(Context context,List<Horizontal> horizontal, int mVertPos)

 { 
       this.mVertPos = mVertPos;
       .......
   }  

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position)
     {

        holder.yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.e("horizontal pos= " +position);
            Log.e("vert pos= " +mVertPos);

        }
    });



}
```

Comment: Hi Am already sending vertical position to Horizontal Recycler Adapter to render items , but my problem is when i click item inside a horizontal recycler view how to find out correct vertical position, For example if my vertical recycler view has 3 items means vertical position will be at 3 only after rendering

Comment: there is a field variable in the horizontal adapter as `mverticalPosition` ... when click the item... get the `mVerticalPosition` as the vertical position clicked..

Comment: get the horizontal position as position in `onBindViewHolder` and vertical postion as `mVerticalPosition` **(which is constant for that particular list)**

Comment: did you get it or shall i update my answer in a better manner ?

Comment: Thank you, i got it